# The static resource cannot be accessed in grails3. How can I fix it?

Tags: grails3

I used grails3.1.2 to create my app. It's normal but now it isn't. My app contains a sub-app which is just html, js, css and so on. I put this sub-app under src/main/webapps folder. From my browser, I found all js and css used by html is not available.

I tried to adjust location of sub-app to src/main/resource/public , but it doesn't work for me.

**My app has a gsp contains html as follow:**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>

%{--<iframe height="100%" width="100%" src="<asset:assetPath src='events-list.html?t=${java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis()}' />" frameborder="0" />--}%
<iframe height="100%" width="100%" src="${resource(dir:'admin',file:'events-list.html')}" frameborder="0" />

</body>
</html>
```

**The html used some js and css:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/h-ui/css/H-ui.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/h-ui.admin/css/H-ui.admin.css"/>
```

But those js and css is not accessed by browser(browser cannot find them)

I don't understand why it got worse. Hope you could submit some advises